# Why does setTime add an hour?

Tags: javascript

This code results in an output of 1. Why is this when the argument to `setTime` is the number of milliseconds added to midnight Jan 1 1970? Surely it should be 0?

```js
var d = new Date();

d.setTime(0);

console.log(d.getHours());
```

Comment: Where are you at the moment? I would guess you are inside the british summer time zone, which is +1 hour ...

Comment: Uh, `setTime` *sets* the entire time object to something new. In particular, it sets it to the "dawn of Unix time" - 1st of January 1970. `getHours` then gives you the hours which will be modified by your timezone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this

```js
    var d = new Date();
    
    d.setTime(0);
    
    console.log(d.getUTCHours());
```

thing is [getHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) give time at your timezone(local timezone), to get the UTC time just change it to [getUTCHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours)